# How to set Symbology On Create Feature Window using arcobjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

programmatically I set the custom symbology for the layers. When i started the edit session programmatically, the create feature window did not show the respective symbology assigned to feature. pl see this screenshot.

[image]

See the Code:

```
'lay' is ifeaturelayer
Dim pLayer As ILayer = lay
Dim pRender As IUniqueValueRenderer
pRender = New UniqueValueRenderer
pRender = TryCast(lay.Renderer, IUniqueValueRenderer)

Dim templateArray As IArray = New Array
subTypeField = pRender.Field(0).ToString

For pp As Integer = 0 To pRender.ValueCount - 1
  Dim newEditTemplate As IEditTemplate = editTemplateFact.Create(pRender.Label(pRender.Value(pp)), pLayer)
  templateArray.Add(newEditTemplate)
Next

pEditor.RemoveAllTemplatesInMap(pMap)
pEditor.AddTemplates(templateArray)

Dim layerExtensions As ILayerExtensions
Dim editTemplateMgr As IEditTemplateManager = Nothing
layerExtensions = pLayer

For j As Integer = 0 To layerExtensions.ExtensionCount - 1
  Dim extension As Object = layerExtensions.Extension(j)
  If TypeOf extension Is IEditTemplateManager Then
    editTemplateMgr = extension
    Exit For
  End If
Next

If Not editTemplateMgr Is Nothing Then
  Dim pEditTemplate As IEditTemplate
  For pp As Integer = 0 To pRender.ValueCount - 1
    pEditTemplate = editTemplateMgr.EditTemplate(pp)
    pEditTemplate.SetDefaultValue(subTypeField, pRender.Label(pRender.Value(pp)).ToString, True)
  Next
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are calling AddTemplates method before calling SetDefaultValue method. I guess this cause the strange result. If calling them at reverse, then I confirmed that it works correctly.

```
'pLayer' is FeatureLayer Object as IGeoFeatureLayer
'pEditor is Editor Object as IEditor3
Dim pRender As IUniqueValueRenderer = TryCast(pLayer.Renderer, IUniqueValueRenderer)

Dim templateArray As IArray = New Array
Dim subTypeField As String = pRender.Field(0)

Dim editTemplateFact As IEditTemplateFactory = New EditTemplateFactory

For pp As Integer = 0 To pRender.ValueCount - 1
    Dim newEditTemplate As IEditTemplate = editTemplateFact.Create(pRender.Label(pRender.Value(pp)), pLayer)
    newEditTemplate.SetDefaultValue(subTypeField, pRender.Label(pRender.Value(pp)), True)
    templateArray.Add(newEditTemplate)
Next

pEditor.RemoveAllTemplatesInLayer(pLayer)
pEditor.AddTemplates(templateArray)
```

In addition, your code uses IEditor::RemoveAllTemplatesInMap method. But it seems that you are editing inside of layer. So it's recommended to use IEditor::RemoveAllTemplatesInLayer method instead of IEditor::RemoveAllTemplatesInMap method . Hope this helps you.